# half-life 2 / portal 2 increase interaction range

Tags: portal-2, half-life-2

i've seen some people on youtube and etc can interact with far away stuff (like, pulling cubes, pressing buttons and pulling levers from far away distance), and as far as i searched through google, games' communities pages on steam, and even asking some people who appeared to know those games a lot, i could not find any console command or other way that would allow me to do so. so how do i do it? things like hl2's gravity gun is not an option, i need to be able to do something like pressing a button from a far away distance (greater than standard distance of `+use`). i think, that if answer suits for hl2, it will suit for poral 2 and vise-versa

Comment: Can you show us any of these videos? It might help us establish how / what they are doing to extend their interaction range. My immediate thoughts are that there may be speedrunning manouvers

Comment: i couldn't find any of this video's, but they all have been about showcasing puzzle's solutions (portal 2 user-created maps), and the way how they grabbed the cube was not any speedrun manouver, guy in video was standing still, looked on the cube far away (> 500 hammer units i would say), presumably pressed the key, and the cube just magnited to him. therefore it's just some console command that increased interaction range, or value in config (if there is any). and question is: what the command or what the value and in which config

Comment: there are multiple occasions of such effect in some video's of this guy https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVs5y3rSbxjiwNnzs442HqQ , but i cant find any particular